# Stuck with SQL query - Learning SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hi I'm learning MYSQL / MariaDB and I'm stuck with making a ranking based on 2 columns

I did this query:

```
SELECT * FROM partides WHERE PUNTUACIO > 0 ORDER BY ID_NIVELL DESC, PUNTUACIO DESC
```

and I got this table and now I want the red table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooxrp.jpg)

Ranking by levels and points (puntuacio) only one nick per user to make a top 5

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must include data as text in the question.

Comment: You SQL query seems to work. It's unclear to me what your desired output should be. "only one nick per user" But what is a user in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT A.ID_PARTIDA, A.NICK, A.ID_NIVELL, MAX(A.PUNTUACIO)
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM partides 
  WHERE PUNTUACIO > 0 
  ORDER BY ID_NIVELL DESC, PUNTUACIO DESC) AS 'A'
GROUP BY A.ID_PARTIDA, A.NICK, A.ID_NIVELL
```